# Query by Attribute Value - VersionOne REST

Tags: rest, versionone

Given a Number Attribute with a specific value, I want to find the story with that value.

For example, I have a request with the number R-56614.

What I'm attempting is along the line of this:

```
rest-1.v1/Data/Story?sel=SuperAndUp&where=Attribute.Number="R-57154"
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

```
rest-1.v1/Data/Request?where=Request.Number="R-57154"
```

Comment: FYI, you can also do rest-1.v1/Data/Request?where=Number="R-57154" since you have specified the root asset as being a Request.  This obviously cuts down some of the redundancy when you start listing multiple attributes with conditions.